# Abrir y cerrar archivos desde archivo .bat

Tags: windows, cmd, batch

Con el siguiente .bat puedo abrir un documento de texto y hacer que se cierre en unos segundos:

```
@ECHO OFF  
START "" notepad.exe "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Documento de texto.txt"  
TIMEOUT /T 5 > NUL  
TASKKILL /IM notepad.exe  
PAUSE  
EXIT
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer lo mismo con una imagen y el Visualizador de fotos de Windows?

He probado a abrir una imagen con el siguiente comando pero solo funciona si la imagen está en el mismo directorio que el .bat y usando "%~dp0":

```
START "" %SystemRoot%\System32\rundll32.exe "%ProgramFiles%\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll", ImageView_Fullscreen %~dp0Imagen.jpg
```

Comment: podrias partir desde aqui: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/45910-reset-windows-photo-viewer-default-open-position-size-windows.html

Answer (score 1):

Hay varios métodos para abrir imágenes desde cmd.

Este método abrirá una imagen usando el visualizador que tengas configurado por defecto en Windows 10, en mi caso es la app Foto:

*abre la imagen:*

```
"D:\Images\Mi foto.png"
```

> Es suficiente pasar el directorio a la imagen, las comillas son solo necesarias en caso de que haya un espacio en el nombre o directorio.

*Cierra la imagen:*

```
TASKKILL /im ApplicationFrameHost.exe
```

> El nombre del proceso cambia según el programa que utilices, puedes averiguar cual es el nombre del proceso usando el comando `TASKLIST /M`

---

Si por otro lado, deseas abrir la imagen con un programa especifico y no deseas configurarlo como visualizador por defecto:

```
START "C:/directorio/programa.exe" "D:/directorio/imagen.png"
```

> Nota que si esto no funciona es un problema ligado al programa que haz elegido y no a CMD.

---

Si por alguna razón, necesitas hacerlo con el programa que dices y solo logras abrir imágenes que se encuentran en el mismo directorio del archivo bat. Puedes probar a cambiar el directorio de trabajo del mismo al de la imagen en cuestión antes de lanzar el comando para abrir la imagen. Simplemente usa `CD "directorio/imagen"` antes de utilizar `"%~dp0"`.

Answer (score 0):

start rundll32.exe C:\WINDOWS\system32\shimgvw.dll,ImageView_Fullscreen ruta_de_la_imagen

Comment: Por favor da un recorrido [Por esta seccion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para que tu respuesta sea de una mejor calidad, sea aceptada y sobre todo que estos no generen puntos negativos.